# How to use other parts of program when loading data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

don't really know how to ask this question. I assume this is related to multitasking or similar.

In form1 there is a menu button for opening form2. In form2 load event I need to load data to populate datagrid.

Im using EntityFramework.

When I press menu button, form2 is shown but without controls until data is loaded, and also cannot use menu on form1 because is stuck in button for opening form2.

Is there way to use other parts of program while loading data, for example click another button for opening calculator (or anything not related to data) in .net 4.5.

Comment: You should take a look at asynchronous programming. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) should help you on your way.

Comment: Thank you. Can someone post simple code for opening form2 with async or something related to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are not taking into consideration that Winforms is using a single UI thread, so when you attempt to load data **synchronously** in your second form using EF, you are actually **blocking** the UI thread, and that is why the second form does not appear immediately.

An obvious solution is to unblock the UI thread, so it is able to paint the second form while data is loading in a background thread, and display data when ready.

One possible approach is to override the OnLoad method in your Form2 class. Then you can use a TPL task to load your EF data in the background in async fashion, and then synchronize the data to the UI thread.

The simplest code i can think of is to use Async/Await with a TPL task:

```
protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    var result = await Task.Run(() => _ctx.MyEntities.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("mx")).ToListAsync());

    // Do stuff with your data
    txtInfo.Text = "Loaded Data";
}
```

the `_ctx` variable is the EF DbContext of your application.

If you don't like the TPL approach above, you can take a look at older API's like `BackgroundWorker` to load the data in the background:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx